# Split a single column into multiple columns based on Rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R that is comprised of a single column containing variables that I ideally would like in multiple columns. The structure of the single column dataframe is this.

```
A1
200
250
Brand x 
A2
400
300
Brand x
A4
100
320
Brand x2
```

I would like to split this column in such a way that it ends up in a multi-column frame like this ("|" is purely to denote a column separator):

```
A1 | 200 | 250 | Brand x  
A2 | 400 | 300 | Brand x1
A4 | 100 | 320 | Brand x2
```

How could I do this? There is at most times a sequence in the horizontal data - for example: 4 variables - A1,200, 250,Brand x. Naive equivalent would be copying and transpose pasting in Excel, but for a predefined sequence of 4 values. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Is it always 4 values?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(df1[,1], byrow=TRUE, ncol = 4))
```

or, equivalently:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(df1[,1],nrow = 4)))
```

In both cases this yields the desired result:

```
#> df2
#  V1  V2  V3       V4
#1 A1 200 250  Brand x
#2 A2 400 300  Brand x
#3 A4 100 320 Brand x2
```

**data**

```
df1 <-read.table(text="A1
                       200
                       250
                       'Brand x' 
                       A2
                       400
                       300
                      'Brand x'
                       A4
                       100
                       320
                       'Brand x2'", header=FALSE)
```

Comment: It's the same as Alexes answer, no?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't check. It has changed so many times that I lost track. This one looks somehow shorter though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I can't see any `as.character`, `stringAsFactors`, `type.convert` or `lapply` here. So I'd say it is different. Except for the result.

Comment: Sorry for that. I misscklicked somewhere at the beginning and published the answer to early.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the results are the same. Try `str(df2)`. All variables should be factors. And when you start working with R it is sometimes easier to do things step by step in order to understand what is going on (at least in my experience as a beginner

Comment: A shorter code doesn't mean it is better. The `matrix(df1[,1], byrow=TRUE, ncol = 4)` is identical copy/paste, while `dat[] <- lapply(dat, type.convert)` is essential and avoiding it make the answer incomplete.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are entitled to your opinion. I didn't copy anything. There are only so many ways data can be transformed. If you really think this is "identical" then we have a different definition of the term. And converting types in the output is just as essential as it might be in the input. I really don't see your point, but I'm not complaining if you feel compelled to downvote my answer.

Comment: If there are many ways that data can be transformed, then show something else rather than `matrix(df1[,1], byrow=TRUE, ncol = 4)` (which already posted). And you can't convert to different types a single column thus your point is invalid.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I won't comment any further on your ludicrous accusations of plagiarism. But there's one thing I'd like to ask you. After downvoting my answer you stated that "dat[] <- lapply(dat, type.convert) is essential and avoiding it make the answer incomplete". Can you please elaborate on that? The OP did not specify any need for type conversion.

Comment: It's not about plagiarism. By "copy/paste" I mean that the answer is identical and shouldn't be posted in the first place. Re `type.convert` is just because if you will do `str(df2)` all the columns will be factors while in fact you have to integer columns. Thus one could not operate on this data set properly. By adding `dat[] <- lapply(dat, type.convert)` the answer becomes much better and more general.

Comment: I removed my DV if it bothers you that much.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ellegant solution but should work.

Some explanations:

The first two lines should only provide the dataframe which you usually obtain by reading in your data.

If there is a character string in a column R will transform this column in a factor variable. For this reason I transformed it in line 3 back to a character vector.

With matrix you can rearrange this vector in the shape you want and than you can transform it back to a dataframe (setting `stringAsFactors=FALSE` to prevent that everything is transformed into factors which would be the default).

However, now all variables are character variables. For this reason you need to encode the variables appropriately.

```
dat<-c("A1",200,250,"Brand x" ,"A2",400,0300, "Brand x", "A4",100,  320,"Brand x2")
dat<-data.frame(dat)
dat<-as.character(dat[,1])
dat<-matrix(dat, ncol = 4, byrow=TRUE)
dat<-data.frame(dat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat[] <- lapply(dat, type.convert)

> str(dat)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "A1","A2","A4": 1 2 3
 $ X2: int  200 400 100
 $ X3: int  250 300 320
 $ X4: Factor w/ 2 levels "Brand x","Brand x2": 1 1 2

> dat
     X1  X2  X3       X4
 1 A1 200 250  Brand x
 2 A2 400 300  Brand x
 3 A4 100 320 Brand x2
```

Comment: Use `dat[] <- lapply(dat, type.convert)` instead of manually doing `as.numeric` and etc. And you still haven't figured out how to identify the number of columns.

Comment: You didn't copy it correctly. You need to add `[]` at the end of `dat`, otherwise you will create a list instead of a `data.frame`

Comment: I did not recognize that but it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint here - if the sequence always repeats (i.e. is deterministic), you could read a vector and change the dimensions, something like:

```
data <- c("A1","200","250","Brand x","A2","400","300","Brand x","A4","100","320","Brand x2")
dim(data) <- c(4,3)
data <- t(data) # transpose
class(data)
data.df <- as.data.frame(data)
class (data.df)
```

This change the dims of the data to a matrix (since internally vector and matrix are stored the same, it's the dimensions that differ).

When executed, it will print

```
> class(data)
[1] "matrix"
> class (data.df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

and the `data.df` is then a data.frame object, so you can do whatever you need to do with the data (e.g. change column to be numeric/character/etc) before processing the data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always 4 values the loop below did the work for me:

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv", sep = ";", header = FALSE)


new.df <- data.frame()
j <- 1
i <- 1
while(i < length(df[,1])-1){

    temp.df <- data.frame()

    temp.df[j,1] <- df[i,1]
    temp.df[j,2] <- df[i + 1, 1]
    temp.df[j,3] <- df[i + 2, 1]
    temp.df[j,3] <- df[i + 3, 1]

    new.df <- rbind(new.df, temp.df)

    j <- j + 1
    i <- i + 4
}
na.omit(new.df)
```

it's not entirely optimized but it does the job! Hope it works for you.